# Beginner: Need to Run a Makefile in Windows

Tags: java, windows, jar, makefile

I am currently trying to install a program from Sourceforge. The installation process requires that I change directory paths in the makefile and execute it. I have been researching how to run the makefile but I am still lost and was hoping to get some help or be pointed in the right direction. I am running Windows 8.1. I believe the program is going to execute a java class file. However, I am unfamiliar with the language and not sure how I should alter the makefile to run in windows 8.1. I tried to run "make" in the command prompt but that didn't work. I posted the makefile below. I understand I should change the directory for ImageJ (which I have installed). But I'm not sure how I should alter path for windows and how I can then execute it. The manual instructs me to change IMAGEJ_DIR to the installation place of the program ImageJ. Then execute "make" and "make install" will generate the jar file. "My imageJ folder is located at C:\Program Files. Do I need to change the directory to execute this makefile, and if so how can I do that in windows? The makefile itself is located in my downloads folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

```
JC=javac IMAGEJ_DIR=/home/wenja/ImageJ PLUGIN_DIR=$(IMAGEJ_DIR)/plugins/OpenBeamProfiler IJ_JAR=$(IMAGEJ_DIR)/ij.jar APACHEMATH_JAR=$(IMAGEJ_DIR)/plugins/commons-math3-3.2.jar LIBJAR=$(IJ_JAR):$(APACHEMATH_JAR) CLASSPATH=$(IMAGEJ_DIR):./:$(LIBJAR) CLASSDIR=./classes COMPILEFLAGS=
COMPILEFLAGS=-Xlint:deprecation
COMPILEFLAGS=-Xlint:unchecked

all: $(CLASSDIR)/BeamProfiler_Plugin.class $(CLASSDIR)/BeamProfilerFrame.class $(CLASSDIR)/BeamProfilerResultFrame.class $(CLASSDIR)/BeamViewWindow.class $(CLASSDIR)/BeamFunctionGauss.class $(CLASSDIR)/BeamFunctionSuperGauss.class

clean: rm -f $(CLASSDIR)/*.class rm -f *.jar

$(CLASSDIR)/BeamProfiler_Plugin.class: BeamProfiler_Plugin.java $(JC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) -d $(CLASSDIR) BeamProfiler_Plugin.java

$(CLASSDIR)/BeamProfilerFrame.class: BeamProfilerFrame.java $(JC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) -d $(CLASSDIR) BeamProfilerFrame.java

$(CLASSDIR)/BeamProfilerResultFrame.class: BeamProfilerResultFrame.java $(JC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) -d $(CLASSDIR) BeamProfilerResultFrame.java

$(CLASSDIR)/BeamViewWindow.class: BeamViewWindow.java $(JC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) -d $(CLASSDIR) BeamViewWindow.java

$(CLASSDIR)/BeamFunctionGauss.class: BeamFunctionGauss.java $(JC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) -d $(CLASSDIR) BeamFunctionGauss.java

$(CLASSDIR)/BeamFunctionSuperGauss.class: BeamFunctionSuperGauss.java $(JC) $(COMPILEFLAGS) -cp $(CLASSPATH) -d $(CLASSDIR) BeamFunctionSuperGauss.java
Note: the "_" in the jar file name in important to be recognized by ImageJ
for including manifest use
jar cfm Beam_Profiler.jar Manifest.txt BeamProfiler_Plugin.class BeamProfilerFrame.class BeamProfilerResultFrame.class
it is important to jar *.class to also get ...$1.class etc.

jar: all cd $(CLASSDIR) &&\ jar cf Beam_Profiler.jar * &&\ mv Beam_Profiler.jar ../

install: jar @if test ! -d $(PLUGIN_DIR); then mkdir $(PLUGIN_DIR); fi
cp Beam_Profiler.jar $(PLUGIN_DIR)

uninstall: rm -f $(PLUGIN_DIR)/Beam_Profiler.jar
```

Comment: Hey @JHermit, I opened the Command Prompt and used the command " `cd Downloads\BeamProfiler_1.3` ". I then edited the makefile to " `C:\Program Files\ImageJ` ". I issued the command `make` but was given the error " make is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Did I maybe put the wrong program directory?

Comment: Also @JHermit, sorry I forgot to mention that my Java JRE is 1.8.0_40

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Open command prompt => Go to windows start menu (run programs) -> type the command "`cmd.exe`"; this will list the command prompt program in the list. Open the command prompt. Probably it'll be defaulted to your home directory. So issue the command "`cd Downloads\directory_of_the_program_to_install`" to navigate to the program directory. Now go to the real program folder, then find that make file, open it in edit mode, and then change the entry 
`IMAGEJ_DIR=c:\program files\imagej_directory`. Then go to the command prompt that we opened before, and issue the command `make` and then `makeinstall`. This would do the trick.

Comment: Update your Java JRE to the latest, say JRE 1.7 or later